# php code inside the search box

Tags: php, search

I am trying to create a search bar for website which searches the database but I find that the code it self is displaying inside the search box

```
<form method="get" action="chalo_search.php">
            <input type="search" name="k" size = "20" placeholder="Enter college name" value = "<?php echo $_GET['k'];?>" autofocus/>
            <input type= "submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
```

is there any error in this

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't enabled on your server.

Comment: Are you sure you are using it on a page which is parsed using PHP? E.g. a `.php` file

Comment: yeah the page is .php and I have xampp installed with php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're echoing $_GET['k'] into the input box. If $_GET['k'] isn't defined, you will get this error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: k in
>    **... yourscript.php** on line **2**

(That's what's appearing in your search box)

Check that $_GET['k'] is defined first:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['k'])){echo $_GET['k'];}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php

$k = $_GET['k'];

echo "<form method='get' action='chalo_search.php'>
<input type='search' name='k' size='20' placeholder='Enter college name' value='$k' autofocus/>
<input type='submit' value='Search'/>
</form>";

?>
```

Comment: There is still the $k inside the search box with the search box ending in ";>" (i mean outside the search box)

Comment: the search box still has $k inside it and there are ;> symbols outside the search box

Comment: make sure $_GET['k']; is defined. What happens if you replace $k with just regular ol' text? like value='blah blah blah'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra spaces when declaring the "value" attribute inside the input element. See below:

```
<input type="search" name="k" size = "20" placeholder="Enter college name" value="<?php echo $_GET['k'];?>" autofocus/>
```